# Cannot read property of NULL

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I have the following html file in which I try to highlight some code using a web worker:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./highlight/styles/default.css">
<script src="./highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

 if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {

     addEventListener('load', function() {
   var code = document.querySelector('#code');
   var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
   worker.onmessage = function(event) { code.innerHTML = event.data; }
   worker.postMessage(code.textContent);
  })
 
 } else {
 }


</script>


<pre><code>
// This is a generated file with many packages
`ifdef MACRO_1
`else
package pkg_1;
  typedef logic [1:0] t;
  typedef enum t {
      IDLE = 2'd0
    , ARMED = 2'd1
    , WRITE = 2'd2
    , BUSY = 2'd3
  } e;
</code></pre>
```

But I get an error saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null (worker.postMessage(content.textContent));

Is there a solution?

Comment: So where's the element with the **ID** `code` ?

Comment: Down bellow? I thought I could make a reference that way to my code written in the <pre><code> block.

Comment: There's no element with that **ID**, just a tagname ?

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, first time writing html/js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add id="code" attribute on code element: https://jsbin.com/daqijafoca/edit?html,output

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./highlight/styles/default.css">
<script src="./highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

    if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {

        addEventListener('load', function() {
            var code = document.querySelector('#code');
            var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
            worker.onmessage = function(event) { code.innerHTML = event.data; }
            worker.postMessage(code.textContent);
        })

    } else {
    }


</script>


<pre><code id="code">
// This is a generated file with many packages
`ifdef MACRO_1
`else
package pkg_1;
  typedef logic [1:0] t;
  typedef enum t {
      IDLE = 2'd0
    , ARMED = 2'd1
    , WRITE = 2'd2
    , BUSY = 2'd3
  } e;
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that solved the error, but I get another one in my highlight file saying : Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /([Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*(<[Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*(\s*,\s*[Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*)*>)?\s+)+[a-zA-Z_]\w*\s*\(/: Range out of order in character class

Comment: You can see your error in Regex101 and try to fix it: https://regex101.com/r/Q85LiX/1. It happens with your special characters.