# Returning a null value which throws a TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, native, typeerror

We're moving off jQuery and I'm swapping out JQuery methods for native browser ones. The prev() method gives an undefined if there is no child sibling before the current element, but the native browser previousElementSibling throws a null error. Is there a way to swap the null for an undefined or 0? I recognize jQuery is handling things that native doesn't.

Here is an example use that throws:

```
pluginInstance[0].previousElementSibling.getAttribute('some-‌​value')
```

Comment: `previousElementSibling` is meant to return `null` not throw an error. Please can you add in a [mcve] so we can see how you are using it?

Comment: Certainly: pluginInstance[0].previousElementSibling.getAttribute('some-value')

Comment: @Rhumborl although as you point out it's impossible to say for sure, the jquery `prev()` method returns an empty jquery object on failure, not undefined. The error is almost certainly "Cannot access previousElementSibling property of null".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a dupe of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527922/cannot-read-property-0-of-null) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203656/cannot-read-property-of-null) and a host of others.

Comment: @SMan as Jared says, `pluginInstance[0].previousElementSibling` returns `null`, and then you are trying to call `null.getAttribute()` whihc throws the error. You need to check for `previousElementSibling` returning `null` before you try to use it.

Comment: @Rhumborl, good point. Thank you.